# MFMessageComposeViewController freezes before displaying the view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm having a problem where every time I click the button that calls on my `MFMessageComposeViewController` nothing happens. More specifically it freezes before it displays the controller and I am not able to do anything.

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)getQuote:(id)sender {
    NSString * inputProduct =_productTextField.text;
    NSString * inputYear = _yearTextField.text;
    NSString * inputMake = _makeTextField.text;
    NSString * inputEmail = email.text;
    NSString * inputDescript = _descript.text;
    emailConfirmation.text = email.text;
    //email subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Love Shack Electronics";
    //email content
    if ([conditionlabel  isEqual: @"Fair"]) {
        NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product:%@    Make:%@   Year Manufactured:%@  Description:%@  Condition:Fair Email:%@",inputProduct,inputMake,inputYear,inputDescript, inputEmail];
        NSArray *recipient = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"LoveShackElectronics@gmail.com"];
        MFMailComposeViewController *SuperLovedEmail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        [SuperLovedEmail setTitle:emailTitle];
        [SuperLovedEmail setToRecipients:recipient];
        [SuperLovedEmail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [SuperLovedEmail setUserActivity:false];
        [self presentViewController:SuperLovedEmail animated:YES completion:nil];
        [SuperLovedEmail setEditing:false];
```

If anyone can help or figure out what is wrong with my code it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running your app in simulator or device?

Comment: Where's the check to see if you can even use email?

Comment: Why do you call `[SuperLovedEmail setEditing:false];`? Don't do that.

Comment: @rmaddy like i said, i'm very new to xcode and objective-C. How would i go about checking if i can use the email?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for `MFMailComposeViewController`. It tells you how.

Comment: Your code is crashing? You didn't mention that in your question. You need to update your question with details about the crash.

Comment: Thankyou to @rmaddy. But i'm confused on how to use the canSendMail method. And im sorry about the misunderstanding, It's not actually crashing, just freezing.

Comment: Do a search on that method name on this site. You'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score -1):

**Please check in device and latest Xcode version. it's work fine. it not work then put into dispatch method like below**

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
^{

    if ([conditionlabel  isEqual: @"Fair"]) 
{
            NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product:%@    Make:%@   Year Manufactured:%@  Description:%@  Condition:Fair Email:%@",inputProduct,inputMake,inputYear,inputDescript, inputEmail];
            NSArray *recipient = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"LoveShackElectronics@gmail.com"];
            MFMailComposeViewController *SuperLovedEmail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
            [SuperLovedEmail setTitle:emailTitle];
            [SuperLovedEmail setToRecipients:recipient];
            [SuperLovedEmail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
            [SuperLovedEmail setUserActivity:false];
            [self presentViewController:SuperLovedEmail animated:YES completion:nil];
            [SuperLovedEmail setEditing:false];
              }
});
```